# order of a sequence of file names

Tags: cmd

I have a sequence of files with names in the following pattern:

```
file2, file3, ..., file 10, file11, ..., file20, ...
```

However, when I use `dir` command in windows' cmd, the above sequence is re-arraged to

```
file10, file11, ..., file2, ...
```

Why so? And how to fix this, please?

Comment: Unless `%DIRCMD%` is set, that's the default order from the file system. NTFS sorts by the ordinal value, in which "10" is less than "2" because "1" is less than "2". `dir` has a `/o` switch for sort options, but unfortunately it's algorithm for sorting by name also doesn't implement a natural sort for numbered files. The way this has been addressed historically is by padding numbers with zeros, e.g. `file02`.

Comment: @eryksun is right. This is usually dealt with by nameing files file001, file002, file010, etc. Windows File Explorer makes some attempt to reorder the file names as you are seeking, but that is not going to do anything for you in a cmd script.